# PHP calendar skips February

Tags: php, function

I have looked and haven't found an answer.

I have a php calendar and when going to next month or previous month fro jan to feb it skips feb and vise versa from march to feb it skips feb. 
It does this every 4 years so I know it has to do with leap year but can't seem to find problem.

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function goLastMonth(month, year){
if (month == 1) {
--year;
month = 13;
}
document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+(month-1)+"&year="+year;
}

function goNextMonth(month, year){
if (month == 12) {
++year;
month = 0;
}
document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+(month+1)+"&year="+year;
}



</script> 




</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['day'])){
$day = $_GET['day'];
}else{ 
$day = date("j");
}
if (isset($_GET['month'])){
$month = $_GET['month'];
}else{
$month = date("n"); 
} 
if (isset($_GET['year'])){
$year = $_GET['year'];
}else{
$year = date("Y"); 
}

// calender variable // 
$currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
$monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp);
$numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp);
$counter = 0;


?> 

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='<' name='previousbutton' onclick="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
<td colspan='5' align='center'> <?php echo $monthName.", ".$year; ?></td>
<td><input style='width:50px;' type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton' onclick="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
<td></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='50px' align='center'>D</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>L</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>M</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>M</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>J</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>V</td>
<td width='50px' align='center'>S</td>
</tr>
<?php 
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++) { 
$timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
if ($i == 1) {
$firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) {
// blank space //
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
} 
}
if ($counter % 7 == 0 && $counter != 0){
echo "</tr><tr>";
}
echo "<td align='center'>".$i."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
?>

</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Your `goLastMonth` and `goNextMonth` seem pretty fishy. Why are you going from "month 1" to "month 13" when you back, but when you go forward you go from "month 12" to "month 0"?

Comment: why don't you take a look at the DateTime object? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['day'])) {
    $day = $_GET['day'];
} else { 
    $day = date("j");
}
```

...

```
$currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
```

If no explicit day is given, you're taking the current day. Guess what, today is the 30th. There is no February 30th. You're then basing all your date calculations on this.

If you want to make a timestamp for a certain month and then iterate through to the next month, always take the beginning of the month. January 1st + 1 month is meaningful, January 30th + 1 month is not.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that Javascript treats January as month 0 while PHP treats January as month 1.

I feel like you've flipped this.

Are you getting your month from javascript or PHP?  If javascript, you should never have month 12.  In either case, you should never have month 13.

Since you said `month` rather than `$month` I'm going to assume it's coming from Javascript.  In that case, I think I would change it like this:

```
function goLastMonth(month, year){
    if (month == 0) {
        --year;
        month = 11;
}
```

...

```
function goNextMonth(month, year){
    if (month == 11) {
        ++year;
        month = 0;
}
```

...